# WCF stops response for requests

Tags: wcf

When maxConcurrentCalls is 100% WCF stops response for incoming requests over existing connections. However, in the same situation, in test enviroment requests come over existing connections well. Requests over new connections timeout as expected. Binding – net.tcp. What can stop request processing over existing connection in production?

Answer (score 1):

After a week of investigation the cause was found. It was an application that issued many requests (and used all available workers - maxConcurrentCalls became 100%). Before receiving replies that app hangs. Because of our app has long send timeout (1 hour) all workers could not send reply during that timeout and just waiting. New request could not be processed because all workers were busy.
All in all long send timeout is evil. If it were short (default 1 minute) hang requests could be aborted mush earlier and another requests could be processed as normal.